# How is the $http cache key created in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, http, caching

I'm trying to remove a specific $http cache entry when I update a resource in Angular JS, but when I try to `get` using the URL as a key it returns `null`. I know the resource is in the cache because when I next fetch the resource I get the old cached value rather than the updated one.

```
var id = 'org.couchdb.user:gareth';
var changes = { ... };
$http.put('/_users/' + id, changes).success(function() {
  $cacheFactory.get('$http').remove('/_users/' + id);
});
```

Why is the cache entry not being removed? What is the correct key to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging through the Angular source it turns out the key is escaped, so in the example the key should be `/_users/org.couchdb.user%3Agareth`.

I updated the code to use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), eg:

```
$http.put('/_users/' + id, changes).success(function() {
  $cacheFactory.get('$http').remove('/_users/' + encodeURIComponent(id));
});
```

For more information on how the key is constructed, check out the `buildUrl` function in the [$http service source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js).